# Sql query by using decode to show grades of employee

Tags: sql

I have a Table **"Emp"** as following

[image]

I want to add another column describing the grades of all employees where

Sal > 100 is 'G1',

Sal > 200 is 'G2',

Sal > 300 is 'G3',

Rest all as 'NA'

I want to use **"Decode"** command to solve this. Please help me with the SQL query

[image]

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm

Comment: @RakeshAnand If you really have to use decode (a question in workbook?) you will need to divide salary by 100, truncate the result and then use `decode(trunc(sal / 100), 0, 'NA', 1, 'G1', 2, 'G2', 'G3')`. Negative salaries, if possible, will fall into 'G3'.

Comment: Actually I had tried this using DECODE(TRUNC (sal/100), 0, 'NA',
                                          1, 'G 1',
                                          2, 'G 2',
                                          3, 'G 3',
                                             'unknown') but the problem is that in the output I am getting grade as G1 who have sal=100, G2 who have sal=200 and G3 who get sal=300

Comment: In that case simply subtract 1 from salary before division (sal - 1) / 100.

Answer (score 3):

```
select 
id,name,sal,
case when sal between 100 and 199 then 'G1'
when sal between 200 and 299 then 'G2'
when sal>=300 then 'G3'
else 'NA' end as grade
from Emp
```

Comment: Thanks Luv for the answer but here I want to use Decode function.

Comment: @RakeshAnand     Please note that
    1. Decode can only be used in SQL
    2. Decode is only for equalities
    
    For your requirement, use the **`CASE`** statement or **`IF..ELSE`** statement

Comment: Dear Luv, I know that DECODE function cannot be used for ranges of numbers. However, we can try to create a formula that will evaluate to one number for a given range, and another number for the next range, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everybody for helping me to reach to the answer.

```
SELECT Name,
       Sal,
       DECODE (TRUNC ( (sal - 1) / 100),
               0, 'NA',
               1, 'G 1',
               2, 'G 2',
               3, 'G 3')
          AS Grade
  FROM Employee;
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to add column in your table

```
Alter table Emp
Add Grade varchar(10)
```

Than you have to update your new field

```
update Emp Set Grade= 'G3' where Sal >= 300 
update Emp Set Grade= 'G2' where Sal >= 200 and < 300
update Emp Set Grade = 'G1' where sal >= 100
update Emp Set Grade = 'NA' where sal < 100
```

Comment: @Ramblin I would like to see that.

Comment: update emp
set grade = case when salary >= 300 then 'G3'
                 when salary >= 200 then 'G2'
                 when salary >= 100 then 'G1'
                 else 'NA'
            end;

Comment: Guys, thank you for your answers but let me make the question more clear to you.I don't want to add any extra column.I want to solve this using 'DECODE' Function.